Multiple GTM variables that can be user_id - how to send the correct one to GA4?
The website I am managing exposes the user's unique ID in a number of different places depending upon the journey they take. The user ID may be retrieved from the data layer a referring URL parameter or a page parameter.
In GTM I am retrieving the user ID and storing in 5 different variables, only 1 of which will have the actual ID - the others will be NULL values.
If I want to send the actual user ID to GA4 using the user_id event parameter how can I select the value that may be in 1 of 5 variables without having the correct value overwritten by NULLs?
I can imagine a JS script might do it, but I don't know where that would live and be executed.

You can use a custom HTML tag within GTM to launch a script. There are a couple good examples here to get you started. You will just need to return the non-null value in the script. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031690/check-if-an-array-contains-something-other-than-null-in-javascript

There's no reason to use 5 variables. Use just one and push it onto data layer with dataLayer.push method, if it's not null. Or respecting any other logic that you wish to use within JavaScript.
Then read the value by creating a custom variable in Google Tag Manager that reads from Data Layer Variable. Use the same name that you're using in dataLayer.push.
